# NSData is null issues

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", item.image];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSDictionary *regsiter=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

NSLog(@"response : %@",[regsiter valueForKeyPath:@"response"]);
```

This NSData values is getting null.
And i need to upload image also same this link how its possible please help me....

Comment: How does urlString look like please?

Comment: can you provide URL please. any single URL that might come in your data.

Comment: If you're getting nil on that dataWithContents... call it's because the URL is wrong or the server/network is hosed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can fetch data from URL asynchronously

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:item.image];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *responce,
                                           NSData *data,
                                           NSError *error) {

                           NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                           NSLog(@"String from URL %@ is %@", url, str);

                       }];
```

Answer (score 2):

If data is null, then it means it could not be created. But if you want to know the reason, you should use `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` method.

Example:

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:nil error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Actually, it's a very good answer.  Failure to use the available error reporting mechanisms caused the OP to ask the question in the first place.

Comment: And should be asked of the OP as a comment so that the error message can be interpreted if necessary.

Comment: Which would likely be pointless, because once you've got the error message, there is little need to interpret it. The answer as it stands can help other people having the same problem, and that's the important bit.

Comment: Besides, you can't stick that example in a comment.